# Some Links not working with JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a web app to learn react and when I tried to make the menu, my menu links doesn't work. The strange thing is that I am using materialize css and the mobile menu works perfectly but in large screens, as my computer, it doesn't work and the Links tags are the same! Help!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Features from './pages/Features';
import Archives from './pages/Archives';
import Settings from './pages/Settings';
import Home from './pages/Home';

class Index extends React.Component{
  print(){
    console.log("TESTE@@@@");
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <nav className="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
              <div id="navbar" className="nav-wrapper container">
                <Link to="/" className="brand-logo">App Teste</Link>
                <div className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <ul className="tabs tabs-transparent" style={{height: 64}}>
                    <li className="tab" style={{paddingTop: 10}}><Link to="features" onClick={this.print}>Features</Link></li>
                    <li className="tab" style={{paddingTop: 10}}><Link to="archives">Archives</Link></li>
                    <li className="tab" style={{paddingTop: 10}}><Link to="settings">Settings</Link></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>


                <ul id="nav-mobile" className="side-nav">
                  <li><Link to="features">Features</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="archives">Archives</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="settings">Settings</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" className="button-collapse"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
              </div>
            </nav>

            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/archives" component={Archives}/>
            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
            <Route path="/features" component={Features}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Index/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

On each of my pages I just have a `<h1></h1>` saying what is the page at the moment. So if it is the Home page it shows Home, if it is the Archives page it shows Archives..

One last thing, when I click at any link, nothing happens, doesn't load the pages and doesn't change the url.

Comment: i think your html elements are overlaying, make sure you can click on the <a> tag on devtool. on chrome inspect element and click on where you clicked when the problem occured. if it directs you to the <a> tag then something else must be blocking the click. as the problem only occurs at large display

Comment: @ReiDien it directs to the <a> tag. I though that this was the problem, but doesn't make sense, it is just a list with the <a> inside each <li>

Comment: that happens much more than you think, :) that depends on how you style your components though. if you want you can also add event listener on your link so you will know that it is really being clicked on large display, and we will start from there :)

Comment: @ReiDien so I added an onClick event in my Link so looks like this now: <Link to="features" onClick={this.print}>Features</Link>. Insite my print function I am just console logging a "TEST@@@" and guess what? It prints TEST@@@ every time that I click on my link! So, now I don't have any idea of what could be the problem at all!

Comment: would you be able to share the whole code to me? i'd like to take a look and see things for myself :)

Comment: @ReiDien Ok, I edited and placed the whole code. So the part that doesn't work is the three first Links and the three last Links works just perfect

Comment: working perfectly for me. i can see that the components are rendered and the url changes on all links.